# What is the term for an inheriting class constructor with different parameters?

Tags: c++, inheritance, terminology

Take the example below.  What term do you use to describe an inheriting class with different parameters then the base class?  I understand that `subbase` is implicitly calling `base()`.  You wouldn't call this overriding, correct, since the base constructor is still called?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
   base()
   {
      cout << "Hello!\n";
   }
};

class subbase : public base
{
public:
   subbase(string s)
   {
      cout << s << endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
   subbase test("Hello World!\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's just a constructor. Just remember that the base subobject needs to be constructed as well...

Comment: @Kerrek SB Yes, as I mentioned in the post, I understand `base()` is called implicitly.  But if one wants to leave a comment to communicate to the implementer that he expects the inheriting constructor to have parameters when the base does not, how would you word that?

Comment: I'd probably talk about "derived class constructors", or "constructors in classes derived from base".

Comment: @Mankarse So would `overload` be applicable like "The derived class constructors should overload the base"?

Comment: I wouldn't use "overload", since there is never any overload resolution between base and derived class constructors (they have different names). I'd word it like "constructors in derived classes should have a different signature from this constructor (`base` constructor)". That said, this seems like a fairly pointless thing to specify, as the whole point of derived classes is to allow variation in state, so it is generally expected that they will not always have identical construction parameters to the base class.

Comment: @jmstoker It's not overloading. It's "The derived class constructors are expected to have arguments different from the base class constructors' arguments".

Comment: @Mankarse that makes sound sense.

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded my friend. It has same method name but differing parameter or return type

But in this case you are just creating whole new constructor. Not really inheriting or anything.

Comment: I've been convinced by comments above that overloading doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading: When you change the signature of the inherited functions in the derived class.

Redefinition(In case of normal functions)/Overriding(In case of virtual functions): When you keep the signature of the base class functions same in the derived class. But you change the implementation part.

But I am not talking in terms of Constructors here. I am talking about the usual member functions of the class.

Comment: You're right about member functions, but this question is strictly talking about the constructors.

Comment: I will hazard a guess that you are perhaps talking about constructor initialization lists. There you pass parameters to the base class cTor from the Derived class cTor if needed. By leaving it out, you can give a hint that base class cTor in effect does not need anything from the Derived class cTor

Comment: Overloading isn't the right term for what I'm describing in my post because the base constructor and derived constructor have different names as @Mankarse pointed out in the comments.  I would have marked his comment as an answer if I could, but he never posted an official solution.